# General method of integration when poles on contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is there a general method for calculating a contour integral when you have a pole on the contour?

For example, how do I integrate, $\frac{1}{z-1}$ over the unit circle centred at the origin?

Comment: If the order of the singularity is $\geq 1$ then the integral won't exist in the standard sense, though you could try to obtain its [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Answer (score 1):

Your contour would look something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156982/residue-theoremwhen-a-singularity-on-the-circle-not-inside-the-circle/1157126#1157126) except you would have an indent at $(1,0)$. Since we are excluding the pole, by Cauchy's integral formula, the integral is equal to zero. Then we can write
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dz}{z-1}
$$
as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dz}{z-1} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\biggl[\int_{\epsilon}^{2\pi-\epsilon}\frac{dz}{z-1}+\int_{\pi}^0\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-1}d\theta\biggr] = 0
$$
where I let $z=1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ in the second integral so $dz = i\epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dz}{z-1}&= -i\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\pi}^0\frac{\epsilon e^{i\theta}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})-1}d\theta\\
&= -i\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\pi}^0d\theta\\
&= i\pi
\end{align}

Comment: I might be wrong but shouldn't the second integral inside you limit technically not be from 0 to $\pi$ but slightly off of those values because in both directions we have advanced slightly along the main circle. I guess the argument for the validity of the above is then it only gives order $\epsilon$ corrections which vanish with the limit.

Comment: @LöweSimon it has been awhile since I looked at this but I believe it should have bounds $[\pi-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ which I suppose I neglected. Feel free to make any corrections if they are needed.

Comment: Sir, In second equation you wrote the integral equal to $0$ and in last you wrote same integral equal to $iπ$? How? Second thing i would like to ask how $-i$ appears?