# Residue theorem definite trigonometric integration

Tags: calculus, integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to solve this integration
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{cos(\theta)} \tan^{3}(\theta)d\theta$$

putting $$z=e^{i\theta}$$
$$\int_{\gamma} e^{(\frac{z^{2}+1}{2z})}\frac{{(z^{2}-1)}^3}{z(z-i)^{3}(z+i)^{3}}d\theta$$

I tried to solve the expression like this
$$=\pi i[\frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z \to i} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z-i)^3f_{2}(z)+\frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z \to -i} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z+i)^3f_{2}(z)]$$
where
$$f_{2}(z)=e^{(\frac{z^{2}+1}{2z})}\frac{{(z^{2}-1)}^3}{z(z-i)^{3}(z+i)^{3}}$$
If the integrand is symmetric around $\pi$, we change limits from $0$ to $2\pi$. (Answer to my previous question on this [Residue theorem:When a singularity on the circle (not inside the circle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156982/residue-theoremwhen-a-singularity-on-the-circle-not-inside-the-circle/1157126#1157126)). However in this particular scenario integrand is not symmetric about $\pi$. Therefore I have a doubt whether I can derive the third equation as written in the form above. Any help on this is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You don't need a branch cut at zero. Zero is a pole.

Comment: @dustin Okay thanks. But can I even formulate that contour as a full circle, since this integrand is not an even function? Bacically can we change the limit to 2 pi?

Comment: You can because $\int_0^{\pi}f(\theta)d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)d\theta$ where $f(\theta) = \tan^3
(\theta)$.

Comment: but say for example f(theta) is not equals to f(-theta) from 0 to pi, so is your above equation correct? (f(theta) should be symmetric about pi to get it as I understood,am I right?)

Comment: in 6th page of http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~pjh/teaching/phz3113/notes/week13.pdf has a similar example and they say function should be even to double the limit from 0 to 2 pi. @dustin Thanks for the help on this

Comment: @dustin I made a mistake in writing the equation. I have an extra exponental term. So this gives me the trouble on finding the contour and also taking pole at z=0 (which gives me exp^{infinity} at z=0)

Comment: I think that any method to solve this integral will lead to the same conclusion : the integral is not convergent. Even if we consider the integral in the sens of Cauchy principal value, it is not convergent.

Comment: Yes. We need a convergent integral on the domain.